# Address memory limit with liipimaginebundle

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.2, liipimaginebundle

I have a problem with image manipulation with liipimaginebundle on symfony. For images larger than 2MB i often get an out of memory error.

This is the config in config.yml :

```
liip_imagine:
    filter_sets:
        main_room_picture:
            data_loader:  room_picture
            filters:
                 thumbnail: { size: [1280, 720], mode: inset }
            post_processors:
                pngquant: { quality: "75-85" }
                mozjpeg: { quality: 70 }
```

As said earlier it works all the time when the picture is not that heavy.

I had to adjust php limit to 512Mo to work around this, but this is huge !!! i do not want to put this in production so i'd like to know if there is a workaround, or if that is the only solution.

By the way setting -1 as memory limit, is it a good practice, does it cause troubles ?

Comment: setting -1 as memory limit means no limit. this is something DDOS'ers really like.

Comment: ok thx somehow i knew its not good to do that ^^